# How did people come up with the product formula for Jacobi's theta function

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, math-history, theta-functions

I understand that the function $\Theta(z|\tau)$, with its definition
$$\Theta(z | \tau) := \displaystyle\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} e^{\pi in^2\tau} e^{2\pi inz},$$
satisfies the product formula
$$\Theta(z|\tau) = \prod(z | \tau) := \prod_{n = 1}^\infty(1-q^{2n})(1 + q^{2n-1}e^{2\pi iz})(1 + q^{2n-1}e^{-2\pi iz}).$$

A proof of this from Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis uses the fact that both function satisfy same two quasi-periodic conditions in $1$ and $\tau \in \mathbb H$ and have common (simple) zeroes. I understand the entire proof given in the book. I also found another proof from [this website](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/02/elliptic-functions-theta-functions-contd.html?m=0) which I only briefly skimmed through.

However, I am unsure how people may have come up with the product formula in the first place. Where did they get the intuition, and how did they develop the actual theorem (that $\Theta = \prod$) from their intuition? I would also be grateful if you could provide some historical context, if you have any knowledge of that.

I would greatly appreciate any input, however small.

Comment: Jacobi introduced these theta functions in his *Fundamenta Nova* in the product form first and then later derived the series form using their properties. The origin of product forms is in the theory of transformation of elliptic integrals which is a major part of *Fundamenta Nova*.

Comment: Jacobi was somewhat of a mathematical magician. I would rank him close to Ramanujan.

Comment: You may try to have a look at this [English translation of Fundamenta Nova (pdf)](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://download.uni-mainz.de/mathematik/Algebraische%2520Geometrie/Euler-Kreis%2520Mainz/Jacobi_Fundamenta%2520Nova.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiNsI-I9p3tAhXn63MBHVsoAoA4ChAWMAV6BAgCEAE&usg=AOvVaw2fAURAaa56tEZHoFLzCPGb). The theory of transformation of elliptic integrals is a complicated topic and I doubt one can provide reasonable details in an answer format here.

Comment: @martycohen: J E Littlewood once said to G H Hardy about Ramanujan: "I can believe that he is at least a Jacobi" and Hardy ranked him even higher. Both Jacobi and Ramanujan used a lot of algebraic manipulation to develop their theories of elliptic and theta functions.